# Mining from multiple machines on a LAN

Tags: mining, solo-mining

If I've installed a full wallet and daemon on a node on my network, how can I also solo-mine from other machines on my network without each of them needing a copy of the entire sync'd data?

Answer (score 1):

Set up your own pool on one machine and run a standalone miner on others (`xmr-stak-cpu` for example). This way you combine the hashing power and get the mined rewards for yourself.